# my wordpress site redirect me to database installation

Tags: wordpress

i hope to find anyone here to help me

i have a big problem , after i moved my site from one host to another and uploaded the database

and changed the configration file it did not work and  **redirect me to database installation**

this is my site

https://www.eldwa.com

```html
define('DB_NAME', 'eldwa_wp3');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'eldwa_wp3');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'J.xvjcyxLU]HhB6(hr.49@^0');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Be sure host name is right : 
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

And also check location of wp-config.php file located in the document root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you made the correct changes to the wp-config files to reflect the database details of the server already. However it looks like the Wordpress installation on this server cannot find this wp-config.php file. Are you sure you have uploaded this to the correct location, i.e. at the document root of Wp installation folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your database hostname is correct

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Also, check the table prefix of your table and in your config file. It means **wp_** prefix will be same in your database.

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```